# com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Unknown authorization header for GCalendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-authentication, authsub

We are using Google Calendar API v2 and V3 with authsub & 2LO and OAuth2.0 authentication for our customers. Most of our customers getting authorization exception frequently. Some are getting inconsistently from last one week. On analyzing our logs, the printstacktrace is

> com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Unknown authorization
>   header   Unknown authorization header
>
> ## Unknown
>   authorization header
>
> ### Error 401
>
> at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:608)
>   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
>   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
>   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
>   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
>   at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135) at
>   com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998) at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
>   at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)

Note: Using API v2 with authsub & 2LO about 2 years.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The same issue is seen in our software recently. We are getting com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Unknown authorization header. Anyone solved this???

Answer (score 1):

Google Account Authentication APIs (**ClientLogin, AuthSub and OAuth 1.0**) are deprecated as per deprecation policy.
http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html

> Important: AuthSub has been officially deprecated as of April 20,
>   2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible